# How to assign a 2d array to a slice of a larger 2d?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a 100x100 array and another 50x50 array. How do I assign the whole 50x50 array to a slice of the larger array

Comment: What type of array?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please elaborate on what array are you using? Also, what have you tried so far? Also, please take a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is this a `numpy` question?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
larger[:50, :50] = smaller
```

it will assign the whole `smaller` array to a slice of the `larger` array.

Answer (score 0):

If your "array" is a two dimensional list it's not possible to do this with one simple statement (you could create a list comprehension but I think it would be unreadable), this solution iterates over the smaller list and replaces one row/slice at a time. The following assumes the "slice" fits within the larger array. You should add checks for this otherwise you will get `IndexError`s when you try to write outside of the limits of the larger array

```
def replace_2d_list_slice(larger_list, smaller_list, row_start, column_start):
    for i, row in enumerate(smaller_list, start=row_start):
        larger_list[i][column_start:column_start + len(row)] = row

replace_2d_list_slice(larger_list, smaller_list, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
x = zeros((50, 50))
y = ones((100, 100))
x[0:50, 0:50] = y[20:70, 40:90]  # x should now be all 1s
```

Comment: OP wants to assign the smaller array to a portion of the larger array.

Comment: @wwii "assign the whole 50x50 array to a slice of the larger array" sounds to me like "I want to assign every value in the 50x50 array to values taken from a slice of the larger array." Please don't downvote me just because this person worded their question in a vague way that permits multiple interpretations